# Copy folder with folder structure intact when parent folder may or may not exist at destination with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, path, copy

I have the look for a folder at three sources and if it exist copy it to the destination.
One folder could exist in multiple places
Source folder structures are :
\\server\Eng\XXX\FolderName
\\server\Prd\XXY\FolderName
\\server\Design\XXZ\FolderName

Destination path should be : \\AnotherServer\Eng\XXX
\\AnotherServer\Prd\XXY
\\AnotherServer\Design\XXZ

XXX,XXY, and XXZ are all numeric characters.
Example source path will look like \\HR\Eng\010\012345 and\or \HR\Eng\010\012345.001

The 012345* folder needs to be found and all its content be copied to \AnotherServer\Eng\010\012345 where Eng, 010 need to be created. This goes smoothly when the first folder is found.
When another folder is found under \HR\Eng\010 new Eng and 010 folders are created. Which of course is not viable. The destination folder structure then looks like
*Eng Eng\010 010\FolderName*

I need that if a folder is found and the destination path \AnotherServer\Eng\XXX already exists the folder and its contents be copied within the XXX folder, if not then create Eng\XXX folder. In the code below I am just experimenting with one destination path first.

```
$invokeSql = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $database -Query $partQuery 
 $partNoList = $invokeSql.PartNo
 $destTest = "\\HR\Copied\"
 
 ForEach($part in $partNoList){
     Write-Host $part
     $path = "\\server1\EngDesignLib\*\$part*"
     $pathEngArc = "\\server1\EngDesignArc\*\$part*"
     $pathDesgLib = "\\server1\PrdDesignLib\*\$part*"
     $pathPrdDesgLib = "\\server1\PrdDesignArc\*\$part*"
 
     $pathCheck = Test-Path -Path $path
     $pathCheckEngArc = Test-Path -Path $pathEngArc
     $pathCheckDesgLib = Test-Path -Path $pathDesgLib
     $pathCheckPrdDesgLib = Test-Path -Path $pathPrdDesgLib
     
     If($pathCheck -or
        $pathCheckEngArc -or
        $pathCheckDesgLib -or
        $pathCheckPrdDesgLib
        ){
         $item = Get-Item -Path $path
         $itemEngArc = Get-Item -Path $pathEngArc
         $itemDesgLib = Get-Item -Path $pathDesgLib
         $itemPrdDesgLib = Get-Item -Path $pathPrdDesgLib
         $src = $item
         $dirRoot = $src | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Parent |Split-Path -Leaf
         $dir = $src | Split-Path -Parent | Split-Path -Leaf
         $destCopy = $destTest+"\"+$dirRoot+"\"+$dir
         $pathDestCheck = Test-Path -Path $destCopy
         Write-Host "Found" $item -ForegroundColor Yellow
         Write-Host "ParentFolder Is" $dirRoot "&" $dir -ForegroundColor Green
         If($pathDestCheck){
             Write-Host "Copy dest folder already exist"
             $destNew = $destCopy+"\"
             Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination $destNew -Recurse
         }
         Else{
             Copy-Item -Path $src -Destination $destCopy -Recurse
         }
         OutputFile -fullPath $src -partName $part
     }
     Else{
         Write-Host "No Part Found" -ForegroundColor Red
     }
 }
```